# "mkdir: cannot create directory '/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/config' [..] Setting HOME to /tmp" when starting Cygwin's terminal

Tags: windows, terminal, cygwin

Suddenly I've been getting the following error when starting up Cygwin's terminal:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/config': Permission denied
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile could not be created.
Setting HOME to /tmp.
```

The terminal was previously working for me without this error. I have not made changes since this the last successful start. I'm not sure why the terminal needs to make a directory in the windows directory, anyway.

I had set the `HOME` variable to be `%USERPROFILE%` as per [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11182877).

If I run the terminal as an administrator, I do not get this error and my home directory is correct.

What could have changed to cause this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `HOME` as a **USER** variable.
I detected the same behavior when it was set as a SYSTEM variable.

Comment: +1, Confirmed this was the fix to the problem.

Comment: How do you do that? Not in the ``/etc/nsswitch.conf``?

Comment: Launch the command (with the keys Win+r) `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` then edit the variables in the upper list (user variables)